# JJTree add methods to node classes

Tags: javacc

So, I'd like to add methods to subclasses of SimpleNode. For example, I have a Position Node. After running jjt and javacc, a Position.java will be generated. It's expected to look like

```
class Position extends SimpleNode {
    private int line, column; // I'll add private members here
    ...
    public int getLine() {
       return this.line;
    } // add some methods here
    ...
}
```

Now, I'm making changes in the generated java files. However, it's not a good idea to do so, as generated java files are frequently removed and jjt file is re-made. Is it possible to add these declarations in jjt file (I didn't find something like this in the manual)? I'm also thinking about deriving subclasses of them. It doesn't work cleanly either.

Comment: Are you using the `NODE_CLASS` variables in your options? See: https://javacc.java.net/doc/JJTree.html

Comment: Yes. The node classes are successfully generated though. The problem is that I don't want to modify them..

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the node implementations all you like.  JJTree will only generate them if they are missing.  From [the manual](https://javacc.java.net/doc/JJTree.html)

> If you don't provide implementations for the node classes JJTree will generate sample implementations based on SimpleNode for you. You can then modify the implementations to suit.

Comment: Thanks! This is useful. I was asking as I'm curious whether there is a way to not modify things generated by Makefile anyway. My current solution is to store anything I want to add by using `jjtSetValue` into value field of a node..

Comment: Well sure; In your make file, you could delete the generated files, run JJTree to regenerate them, and then modify the resulting files with sed or awk or whatever before compiling.  This seems more complicated than need be. What I do is edit the generated files and check them into the source repository. The only danger is that when there is a new version of JJTree your node files generated by the old version won't be compatible; I would say there is a low chance of that happening. I've had it happen with ParseException, but I don't think it will happen with node classes.